# Tri band router and wifi extenders: how to organize my local wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a small hosting business with guests coming in and out of my house all the time, so I wanted to upgrade the wifi system in my house to meet the guests' needs and my own in the best conditions.

My internet provider offers a theoretical speed of 75Mb/s.

I bought a TP link AC3200 router which offers:

- Tri band wifi (one 2.4GHz (600Mbps) and two 5GHz (1300Mbps each))
- Possibility to create a guest network (or several, one for each band).

The "smart connect" option allows me to show only one network (out of three, one for each band) and let the devices connect to the best one automatically. However "smart connect" does not seem to be available for the guest network.

I had previously been using Wifi extenders to give better access to the remote rooms of the house, however I am not sure how they deal with the tri band business (badly, on first impression).

Any suggestions how I should organize my home wireless network?

**Edit:** Answering the question in the comments:

- I have only one router (the AC3200, replacing my old router), connected to a modem, and one or two extenders.
- The devices that need to use the internet are my own (PC, laptop and phone) and the guests' (3-4 people using laptops, tablets and phones).

Comment: We need a lot more information - like how many AP's, what devices are connecting to it etc.

Comment: @davidgo please see edited question

Answer (score -1):

If this was my network I'd turn off Smart Connect and configure three SSIDs for each of the two 5Ghz radios, and the single 2.4Ghz radio. This will reduce confusion as well as give a 1:1 relationship to SSID and radio. If this is the device after your modem (upstream router), it should also be the only device running and NAT and DHCP.

I'd use the strongest 5Ghz for my devices near the primary router.

I'd use the second and lower signal 5Ghz for wireless range extenders, and only connecting wireless clients to the extenders, not the primary router**. If the extenders are wired, then it shouldn't matter if "Smart Connect" is on. However there are known issues with Android devices and Wireless AC, especially with "Smart Connect" AP's. I personally have experienced this with my dual TrendNet TEW-828DRU AC3200 setup.

Then I'd use the 2.4Ghz for guests and legacy devices. It's the most compatible and typically has the greatest range. I'd also limit the bandwidth to 20Mhz for greater range and reliability from interfering Bluetooth, microwave, cordless phones, etc.

**If your downstream range extenders are wireless and can function as a Wireless bridge I'd assign them to the weakest 5Ghz signal since the two have the power to "meet in the middle" with the upstream router so the downstream connected clients don't have to reach as far. If they're wired extenders then I'd give them the same SSID and security as the upstream router, but make sure they're using different channels. I find it best to manually set the primary router's channels, and set downstream wired APs to "Auto", again only if they're WIRED repeater APs. In this way the downstream will avoid using the same channel as the upstream (and neighboring channels) and the coverage won't be as diminished. Setting the downstream repeater channels is fine as well, but depending on where they're located it may be impacted by your neighbor's Wi-Fi using the same channel, reducing the output of yours.

I hope that helps. As stated above I run two Tri-band (AC3200) devices and a single Amped Wireless SR20000G. One AC3200 is the primary, and the remaining two APs are downstream wireless bridge repeaters.